# Почему не работает js скрипт?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

```html
<img src="img/close.svg" alt="Web" class="modal__close">
<a href="javascript: void 0" class="button">Записаться на прием</a>
<div class="modal"></div>
```

Имеется скрипт:

```js
$('.button, .modal__close').click(function() {
  if ($('.modal').hasClass('.modal__active')) {
    $('.modal').removeClass('modal__active');
    $('body').css('overflow', 'unset');
  } else {
    $('.modal').addClass('modal__active');
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  }
});
```

Почему то событие срабатывает при клике на `.button`, но не срабатывает при клике на `.modal__close`, это картинка (Я пробовал использовать другие классы но они так же не работают) В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Приведете код `html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас всё срабатывает. Вы ошиблись в (убрать `.`):

```
$('.modal').hasClass('.modal__active')
```

```js
$('.button, .modal__close').click(function() {
    console.log('click');
  if ($('.modal').hasClass('modal__active')) {
    $('.modal').removeClass('modal__active');
    $('body').css('overflow', 'unset');
  } else {
    $('.modal').addClass('modal__active');
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="img/close.svg" alt="Web" class="modal__close">
<a href="javascript: void 0" class="button">Записаться на прием</a>
<div class="modal"></div>
```

> P.S. Учитесь дебажить код.

Comment: Точно, огромное спасибо :)

Comment: @DaniilLav галочку?)